# How to change the width of UINavigationItem::leftBarButtonItem?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

is it possible to change the width of the leftBarButtonItem of the class UINavigationItem?

The default width is actually to short for my strings and I would like to enlarge the item as I have no title.

Best,
heinrich

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't find an answer yet, take a look at the width property for UIBarButtonItem.

From the SDK:

width

The width of the item.

```
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat width
```

Discussion

If this property value is positive, the width of the combined image and title are fixed. If the value is 0.0 or negative, the item sets the width of the combined image and title to fit. This property is ignored if the style uses radio mode. The default value is 0.0.